# How to print without file name and page number in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I searched through print preference but

I can't find how to print without file name

and page number.

Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had checked out the eclipse->window->preferences and even checked the [`org.eclipse.swt.printing.PrintDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/printing/PrintDialog.html) details for eclipse. But there is no in-build way to do it.

Only thing that can be done is create your own plugin for printing using eclipse.

Or even try to replace the class `org.eclipse.swt.printing.PrintDialog` in the jar corresponding to it. I should work.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Babu!.